# Is ‘a dog which is barking’ synonymous with ‘a barking dog’?

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, differences

I am wondering whether *a barking dog* means the same as *a dog which is barking*.

Here is the saying *a barking dog does not bite*. Does *a barking dog* herein mean *a dog which tends to bark in face of threat* or *a dog which is barking*?

Similarly, could *I saw a patient coughing* be rephrased as *I saw a coughing patient*?

Besides, does *a waiting car* refers to a car that is arranged a priori to pick sb. up or a car that happens to be seen waiting, say for passengers getting in or for a traffic light turning green?

Also, *sleeping* as an adjective collocates with *child*, as in this ODE example *a sleeping child*; could one likewise say *a sleeping student/lady/man/etc.*?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Both are probably correct, but being pedantic I’d argue they can have slightly different connotations. To focus on one of your examples,

> I saw a patient who was coughing

This implies that the patient was coughing when you saw them. You could argue however that this also has an implication of being temporary.

> I saw a coughing patient

While this also implies that you saw a patient who was coughing, one could argue that in this context, it becomes a more permanent attribute as if they were known for it. “Oh, don’t worry about him, that’s the coughing patient. That’s normal. “

Comment: Quite right. Most people would not make the distinction. But a dog that is *known* to bark (*that annoying barking dog*) need not necessarily *be* barking at the time it's referred to in that way. In the same way, you could describe somebody as a happy, annoying, talkative, quiet, or what have you, person. That just describes their *general* demeanour or behaviour—it doesn't mean they are *always* like that.